Supermicro H11SSL-i won't POST
I just got a used H11SSL-i (rev 2.0). I connected power, added a CPU and cooler, and a stick of RAM to the 2nd slot (C1). When I power it on, I get nothing on VGA, and no POST beep. The fans start slow, and then ramp up to full speed, and they just stay on at full speed. The BMC LED blinks like it should, and the motherboard's power LED lights up like it should. All jumpers are in their default positions. How can I diagnose the problem further?
I've also been unable to access IPMI. I attempted to reset the CMOS by shorting the two half-circle-shaped contacts for at least 10 seconds with the battery out and power off, but according to my router it still powers up with a random IP that I didn't assign (10.128.188.233 is not in any of my subnets). The "link" and "activity" LEDs are amber (looks like red?) and yellow respectively. Web connections to http://10.128.188.233:80 time out. nmap 10.128.188.233 -Pn shows that port 53 is open for some reason, but I can't get anything useful to happen on that port. The fact that it still has a static IP makes me think I haven't successfully cleared the CMOS, so what else should I try? Assuming I can connect to IPMI, this would allow me to get some POST diagnostic information, right?

This isn't a forum for resurrecting dead hardware.

@GregAskew I found several questions here on similar subjects with multiple upvotes and answer. I also checked the site details, and it says to ask about server hardware in a business environment. If you don't know the answer, that's fine, but I did my best to research the question and put it in the right place.
